# Is it possible to add headings to a jEditable select drop down

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins, jeditable

Is it possible to add `headings` to a `jEditable` select drop down?

I want to add headings to data sets in a single select.

This would be the equivalent to `OPTGROUP` in an `HTML` select.

If this possible?

If so how?

If not, any ideas where I'd start to extend to to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

If you use jEditable in it's pure downloaded form, you cannot implement option grouping within the select.
On the other hand, jEditable isn't such a complicated java file, and you might want to try to add in an option to insert OPTGROUP tags:

maybe something that looks like :

```
            $("#ddlGrouped").editable("url", {
            type: 'select',
            submit: 'OK',
            data: {
                   'Swedish Cars' : { 'volvo': 'Volvo', 'saab': 'Saab'},
                   'German Cars' : { 'mercedes': 'Mercedes', 'audi': 'Audi'}
                  }
        })
```

Here's the part of jEditable that builds the select:

```
select: {
            element: function (settings, original) {
                var select = $('<select />');
                $(this).append(select);
                return (select);
            },
            content: function (data, settings, original) {
                /* If it is string assume it is json. */
                if (String == data.constructor) {
                    eval('var json = ' + data);
                } else {
                    /* Otherwise assume it is a hash already. */
                    var json = data;
                }
                for (var key in json) {
                    if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ('selected' == key) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    var option = $('<option />').val(key).append(json[key]);
                    $('select', this).append(option);
                }
                /* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */
                $('select', this).children().each(function () {
                    if ($(this).val() == json['selected'] ||
                        $(this).text() == $.trim(original.revert)) {
                        $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                });
            }
        }
```

But you'd also have to check how jEditable gets the selected item, and maybe adapt that code too. Sounds like fun to do, but at the moment I don't have the time to try it out and post the working code.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Rafael's answer I had a go at creating this tonight and have it working for my purpose. Please note I didn't make this flexible, I've just hacked it for my purposes (2 OPTGROUP, always the same headings). Also I don't actually know how to program in JS (as you'll see) so this is just posted as a working solution, certainly not best practice.

Very happy for people to point out the mistakes in my code also - just posted here incase someone else comes across the same issue.

Updates to jeditable below - call to this is as described in Rafael's post (except type is "selectactioner".

```
        selectactioner: {
           element : function(settings, original) {
                var select = $('<select />');
                $(this).append(select);
                return(select);


            },
            content : function(data, settings, original) {

               var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
               var json = obj.attendees;
               var json2 = obj.nonattendees;

                var optgroup = $('<optgroup />');
                optgroup.attr('label', 'Meeting Attendees');
                $('select', this).append(optgroup);

                for (var key in json) {
                    if (!json.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ('selected' == key) {
                        continue;
                    } 
                    var option = $('<option />').val(key).append(json[key]);
                    $('select', this).append(option);    
                }                    
                /* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */ 
                $('select', this).children().each(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() == json['selected'] || 
                        $(this).text() == $.trim(original.revert)) {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                });




                var optgroup = $('<optgroup />');
                optgroup.attr('label', 'Other Users');
                $('select', this).append(optgroup);

                for (var key in json2) {
                    if (!json2.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    if ('selected' == key) {
                        continue;
                    } 
                    var option = $('<option />').val(key).append(json2[key]);
                    $('select', this).append(option);    
                }                    
                /* Loop option again to set selected. IE needed this... */ 
                $('select', this).children().each(function() {
                    if ($(this).val() == json2['selected'] || 
                        $(this).text() == $.trim(original.revert)) {
                            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected');
                    }
                });


            }
        }
```